# Understanding the co-variant derivative

Tags: vectors, tensors, covariance

I am taking a theoretical physics module and we are currently going over 4-vectors and tensors, I am finding it hard to get my head around the notion of the covariant derivative. I have been told that:
$$\partial=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^0},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^2},\frac{\partial}{\partial x^3}\right).$$
and hence for any function on spacetime $f(x)$,
$$\partial f=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^0},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^1},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^2},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^3}\right).$$
I have then been given:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}=\sum_{\nu=0}^{3}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{'\nu}}\frac{\partial x^{'\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}}.$$
I am completely lost as to how to get from $\partial f$ to $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^{\mu}}$.

---

I was under the impression that $f$, being a function of space time, would be a 4-vector:
$$f=\begin{pmatrix}x^0\\x^1\\ x^2 \\x^3 \end{pmatrix},$$
and that:
$$\partial f=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial f^0}{\partial x^0} & \frac{\partial f^0}{\partial x^1} & \frac{\partial f^0}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial f^0}{\partial x^3}\\\frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x^0} & \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x^1} & \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial f^1}{\partial x^3}\\ \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x^0} & \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x^1} & \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x^3} \\\frac{\partial f^3}{\partial x^0} & \frac{\partial f^3}{\partial x^1} & \frac{\partial f^3}{\partial x^2} & \frac{\partial f^3}{\partial x^3} \end{pmatrix}.$$
This is clearly not the same, I think I my matrix manipulation is the problem, if someone could let me know why it is in the form of a summation, that'd be great. Thanks.

Comment: A function of a vector can be a scalar.

Comment: The expression for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^\mu}$ is simply a transformation of coordinates and uses the chain rule.

Comment: I just answer that.

Comment: sorry, I somehow forgot that the chain rule was the sum of derivative, Thank you.

Comment: In the summation, we take the derivative with respect to $x^{'\nu}$ rather than $x^{\nu},$ is there any specific reason for this? $$ x^'=\Lambda x $$